# android app crashing: code posted

Tags: android

hey i haave been searching for a while now and have tried multiple times to solve an error at updateUI();. I cant get it to work, the app keeps on crashing at launch. The code is posted

"Unable to start activity ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private TextView txtStatus;
private ImageView imageView;
int i=0;
int imgid[]={R.drawable.new_york_city_1,R.drawable.facebook,R.drawable.groupsms,R.drawable.twittersms };
RefreshHandler refreshHandler=new RefreshHandler();

class RefreshHandler extends Handler{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainActivity.this.updateUI();
    }
    public void sleep(long delayMillis){
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
};
public void updateUI(){
    int currentInt=Integer.parseInt((String)txtStatus.getText())+10;
    if(currentInt<=100){
        refreshHandler.sleep(2000);
        txtStatus.setText(String.valueOf(currentInt));
        if(i<imgid.length){
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[i]);

            i++;
        }
    }
}@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("DJUICE");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "djuice"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(s);

    this.txtStatus=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textViewM);
    this.imageView=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageViewM);
    updateUI();
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<TextView android:text="10"
          android:id="@+id/textViewM"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageViewM"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></ImageView></RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{runaway.fridge.potohar/runaway.fridge.potohar.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4898):    at 
runaway.fridge.potohar.MainActivity.updateUI(MainActivity.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4898):    at 
runaway.fridge.potohar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
```

Comment: You should have an if statement to test if "txtStatus.getText()" and/or "txtStatus.getText().toString()" is null before you try to parse it.
Whenever dealing with input you should probably do this.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you're calling `updateUI()` which is trying to do

`Integer.parseInt((String)txtStatus.getText())+10;`

before a value is put into the field. Meaning it's trying to parse nothing and there's your NullPointer.

To test it is that, just add `txtStatus.setText("10");` before `updateUI()` and see if you stop getting the crash.

If it is that, which it is, just check for `null` when getting that input to stop the crash.

Also, no need to cast `(String)txtStatus.getText()` just do `txtStatus.getText().toString();`

Comment: @user2558344 Just call updateUI(); only after some text has been placed in the field. Try the code in my answer to see if that stops the crash.

Comment: Surround the inside of updateUI() with `if(txtStatus.getText() != null){ }`

Comment: its still the same, i dont think it has anything to do with no value to parse after the last attempt.

Comment: Hm. Weird. Can you post the XML file? I'll recreate it and test it.

Comment: i didnt post my whole fragment activity. just the part where the error was occuring. here is the whole, i dont know if it'll e of much help, http://pastebin.com/xE5aRpv9

Comment: Can't see any issues in there. But add that and your XML to the OQ. For all of us here it looked as though that was it.

Comment: how about this. my fragment loads the drawer layout xml of the android navigation drawer, which then refers to a first fragment class in which my xml for this is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want this in updateUI()

```
int currentInt=Integer.parseInt(txtStatus.getText().toString())+10;
```

Comment: That helps, but it's not the cause of the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added the activity to the Manifest. Normally that would cause this issue,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package.name">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
</application>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: If the Activity wasn't added, the `logcat` would straight out tell you to add it.